# Spring Expression Language cannot resolve method on class

Tags: java-8, spring-el

I'm trying to evaluate some expression written in SpEL programmatically.

```
ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression(annotation.filter());

SimpleEvaluationContext context = SimpleEvaluationContext.forReadOnlyDataBinding().build();
context.setVariable("authorities", authentication.getAuthorities());

return expression.getValue(context, Boolean.class);
```

As you can see, I add a variable, called `authorities`. I'm trying to evaluate this expression: `#authorities.isEmpty()`.

But I get the exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method isEmpty() cannot be found on type java.util.ArrayList
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:225) ~[spring-expression-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:134) ~[spring-expression-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ...
```

Anyone knows a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SimpleEvaluationContext` does not allow arbitrary method invocation. See its Javadocs.

If you "trust" the SpEL expression, use

```
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
```